# Installing software from RPMForge repo

Tags: linux, centos, vps, openvpn

I have a centos 5 x86 vps and I want to install openvpn in the easiest and fastest way possible. So I decided to use a repo. The [rpmforge](http://packages.sw.be/openvpn/) repo has openvpn.

As you can see, that link shows that there are many versions of openvpn available in the repo. If I just type 'yum install openvpn' how do I know it will install the newest version available in the repo? Should I instead do something like:

```
yum install openvpn-2.1.4-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to do two things to use the RPMForge repository. You'll need to install the rpmforge-release package so the rpmforge repository will be available to yum:

```
rpm -ivh http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm
```

Further instructions for enabling RPMForge are available here:
http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge?action=show&redirect=Repositories%2FRPMForge#head-5aabf02717d5b6b12d47edbc5811404998926a1b

Then you can simply:

```
yum install openvpn
```

The newest version available at RPMForge will be installed, along with dependencies. Choosing the newest available version is inherent in the "yum install" operation.

Answer (score 2):

First, install the repo:

```
wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm
rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
rpm -K rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm
rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm
rm rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm
yum update
```

Then you can install the latest version of OpenVPN with this command:

```
yum install openvpn
```

If you need any additional help to set up your VPN try reading [this handy guide](http://www.shorewall.net/OPENVPN.html).